# How to access a class from one cuda kernel in the next kernel

Tags: c++, class, cuda

I have a dev variable which I used to allocate space on the device using a class header.

```
Neu *dev_NN;
cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_NN, sizeof(Neu));
```

Then I call a kernel which initialises the class on the GPU.

```
KGNN<<<1, threadsPerBlock>>>(dev_LaySze, dev_NN);
```

in the kernel

```
__global__ void KGNN(int * dev_LaySze, Neu * NN)
{
    ...
    NN = Neu(dev_LaySze[0], dev_LaySze[1], dev_LaySze[2]);
}
```

After the return of this kernel I want to use another kernel to input data to class methods and retrieve output data (the allocators and copies are already done and work), such as

```
__global__ void KGFF(double *dev_inp,  double *dev_outp, int *DataSize)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    ...
    NN.Analyse(dev_inp, dev_outp, DataSize );
}
```

The second kernel knows nothing about the class that was created. As you would expect NN is unrecognised. How do I access the first NN without re-creating the class and re-initialising it? The second kernel has to be called several times, remembering the changes it made to the class variables earlier. I don't want to use the class with the CPU, only the GPU, and I don't want to pass it back and forth each time.

Comment: Pass it as argument?

Comment: Pass *a pointer to* `NN` as an argument to your second kernel, just as you have in your first kernel.  And you would do `NN->Analyse` not `NN.Analyse`  I don't think this quesion really has anything to do with CUDA.  A similar problem would be observed in ordinary C++ and the solution could be the same.  @ParkYoung-Bae if you want to provide an answer I would upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with CUDA, actually.  I believe a similar problem would be observed if you tried this in ordinary C++ (assuming the pointer to `NN` is not a global variable).

The key aspect of the solution as pointed out by Park Young-Bae is simply to pass the pointer to the allocated space for `NN` to both kernels.  There were a few other changes that I think needed to be made to what you have shown, according to my understanding of what you are trying to do (since you haven't posted a complete code.)  Here's a fully worked example:

```
$ cat t635.cu
#include <stdio.h>

class MC {

  int md;
  public:
  __host__ __device__ int get_md() { return md;}
  __host__ __device__ MC(int val) { md = val; }
};

__global__ void kernel1(MC *d){

  *d = MC(3);
}

__global__ void kernel2(MC *d){

  printf("val = %d\n", d->get_md());
}

int main(){

  MC *d_obj;
  cudaMalloc(&d_obj, sizeof(MC));
  kernel1<<<1,1>>>(d_obj);
  kernel2<<<1,1>>>(d_obj);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t635 t635.cu
$ ./t635
val = 3
$
```

The other changes I suggest:

1. in your first kernel, you're passing a pointer (`NN`) (which presumably you have made a device allocation for), and then you are creating an opject and copying that object to the allocated space.  In that case I think you need:

   ```
   *NN = Neu(dev_LaySze[0], dev_LaySze[1], dev_LaySze[2]);
   ```
2. in your second kernel, if `NN` is a pointer, we must use:

   ```
   NN->Analyse(dev_inp, dev_outp, DataSize );
   ```

I have made those two changes to my posted example.  Again, I think this is all just C++ mechanics, not anything specific to CUDA.

Comment: I'm thinking we might be missing something as the solution seems "too simple", but upvoted regardless.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work now, but I am concerned that the first kernel creates arrays in the class based on the sizes contained in LaySze and the cudaMalloc cannot take these into account. Presumably the array pointers in the class keep track of these between calls.